# Google Managed Certificate with ip address

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate, google-compute-engine, load-balancing

I am tryin to create a Google Managed SSL Certificate for my compute engine instance. However, I am required to enter a domain. The issue is, I do not have a domain associated with my instance, I only have its external ip address.

How can I use the ip address of my instance for the certificate, or how do I associate it with a domain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You might be confusing what Google is asking for.

In order to create an SSL certificate, you must own / manage /control a domain name.

Next, in order to use the SSL certificate that Google created (or by other means such as Let's Encrypt), you map the Google Service, such as a load balancer, to a backend such as Google Compute Engine VM instances.

If your goal is to create an SSL certificate using an IP address - you cannot. SSL certificates require a domain name. There are exceptions to this, such as using a machine name to create a self signed certificate, but this does not apply to your situation.

Another important item. Once you create a Google Managed SSL certificate, you cannot use it on your VM instance. You can only use it for Google managed services such as Load Balancer. The Load Balancer will then sit in front of your VM instance.

If your goal is to create an SSL certificate that you can install on your VM instance, look into [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). Let's Encrypt is simple to work with and their certificates are free. You will still need to own a domain name, but you will be able to control where it is installed.

Once you install a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate, you modify the DNS servers that your domain registrar setup to point your domain name to an IP address.

Comment: I have decided to use a Google Managed Certificate and am just using a domain name that I remembered was lying around. Running `host mydomain.com` shows that the domain is connected to a static IP that I would like to use. However, I am getting the certificate error: `host mydomain.com`. My backend is healthy and I have configured the loadbalancer.

Comment: When trying to visit `www.mydomain.com` I get a `ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH` error.

Comment: @HarryStuart - Using Chrome, go to your website with the error. Next to your URL is a lock icon. Click on it. Then click on Certificate. What does it show for "Issued to". Click on the details tab. What does it show for "Subject Alternative Names". Your domain name must be included in "Issue to" and/or "Subject Alternative Names". If those match, then go to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html and look at the errors. This will indicate what to fix.

Comment: Sorry, I mean to say that the certificate error I was getting is: `FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE`.  I can't find any lock icon the page simply says: `The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.`

Comment: The status FAILED_NOT_VISIBLE indicates that certificate provisioning failed for a domain because of a problem with DNS or the load balancing configuration. Make sure that DNS is configured so that the certificate's domain resolves to the IP address of the load balancer.

Comment: Running `tracert www.mydomain.com` gives the IP of the url as the IP of the load balancer.

Comment: It acknowledges that the IP address is the same as the load balancer IP but says `Assessment failed: Failed to communicate with the secure server`

Comment: The address is `www.zenithaerial.com.au` if that helps.

Comment: HTTPS is working for your website correctly. HTTP fails with a 404 error. This means that your configuration for HTTP is incorrect.

Comment: I just tested it! It works even though it didn’t work half an hour ago. The certificate now says it’s ‘ACTIVE’. It was throwing that error before, did it just need time?

Comment: Yes, it can take a small amount of time for Google to deploy the certificate and install it on your server. Typically 5 - 10 minutes, but longer can happen.